# Replace <Unknown Source> in Java Rhino (JSR223) with actual file name

Tags: java, rhino, jsr223

In my code, all of the scripts are contained in .js files. Whenever one of the scripts contains an error, I get this:

javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "nonexistant" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#5) in <Unknown source> at line number 5

What bugs me is the <Unknown Source>. Multiple files are in one ScriptContext, and it can be hard to track down an error. It also looks horrible.

Is there a way to replace <Unknown Source> with the actual file name? None of the methods I see support passing a File object, so I'm really confused  here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the ScriptEngine.FILENAME constant:

scriptEngine.put(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, scriptFile.toString());

Answer (score 6):

The question hasn't been specifically asked yet, but I thought I'd offer this to anyone who stumbles upon this topic in the future: this will change when Java 8 is released and we move from Rhino to Nashorn as the underlying JavaScript engine. Under Nashorn, the file name is applied to the ScriptContext, rather than to the ScriptEngine itself:

```
ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
context.setAttribute(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, "test.js", ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
try
{
    engine.eval(script, context);
}
catch (ScriptException e)
{
    /* e.getFileName() will return "test.js" */
}
```

If you attempt to apply the file name using ScriptEngine.put(), as you do under Rhino, nothing will happen and your exceptions will return "<eval>" as the file name.

I would imagine that a few people will run into this issue in the coming months, so thought I'd offer it. This does not appear to be documented anywhere. I had to dig into the Nashorn source code to figure it out.

Comment: Bonus points for this one! Java 8 is long out and Java 9 coming shortly. :)

Answer (score 3):

The Java 8 (Nashorn) way of setting the filename for the script engine through the ScriptContext figured out by mattj65816, works for the Rhino engine as well. So, I'd recommend using only

```
context.setAttribute(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, "test.js", ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
```

since this piece of code works for both common JavaScript engines. You don't event need to create you own context, but only set the attribute to the engine's default context:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
if (engine != null) {
    ScriptContext ctx = engine.getContext();
    ctx.setAttribute(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, "test.js", ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perfect!

```
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
    // javax.script.filename
    engine.put(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, "test1.js");
    try {
        engine.eval("function throwError1(){throw new Error('test, haha')}");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
    }       

    engine.put(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, "test2.js");
    try {
        engine.eval("function throwError2(){throw new Error('test2, haha')}");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
    }
    try {
        engine.eval("throwError1()");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        engine.eval("throwError2()");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

output :

```
Error: test, haha in test1.js at line number 1
Error: test2, haha in test2.js at line number 1
```